# How to use a list of indexes as a variables inside a Module?

Tags: functions, scoping, indexed-variable

This is a trivial function, just to show that Module does not recognize the list generated by Table.

```
f1[x_] := Module[Table[out[i], {i, 1, Length[x]}], 42]
f1[{1, 2, 3}]
```

Comment: Only the base variable needs to be specified in the `Module`. For example, `f1[x_] := Module[{out}, Table[out[i] = x[[i]], {i, 1, Length[x]}]; out[1] + 2*out[2] + out[3]^2];` then `f1[{1, 2, 3}]` evaluates to `14` and neither `out` nor its indexed values are defined in the global name space.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is your desired output from this f1?

Comment: ok Bob this is what I need, many thanks

Answer (score 4):

In an even more trivial case. It appears that Module is not willing to recognize such indexed variables as symbols:

```
f2[x_] := Module[{out[1]}, out[1] = x; out[1]]

f2[5]

Module::lvsym: Local variable specification {out[1]} contains out[1], which is not a symbol or an assignment to a symbol

Module[{out[1]}, out[1] = 5; out[1]]
```

Comment: Correct. You can only localize symbols; not arbitrary expressions.

Answer (score 3):

According to the `Help`, ''Every time a module is evaluated, a new temporary symbol is created'' and ''Block localizes values only; it does not create new symbols''

```
Clear["`*"]; 
f1[x_] := Block[{out}, Table[out[i], {i, 1, Length[x]}, 42]]
f1[{1, 2, 3}]
```

Comment: I do not understand the output of this